# Decode Zlib and base64 расшифровка

Tags: base64, decode, zlib

Есть онлайн декодер который декодирует мою строку правильно. Если ввести сюда https://jgraph.github.io/drawio-tools/tools/convert.html строку "7P1pbxvJtjXqfr+/Qnd92huoKrFVk8ABXhUl1+td7iDJ68L3+IBISbTMpYa+pMQq1cH57zeSndjMmZEyqYwYkwN7G7UsU1SMZIQ4Hmb3f9Yq1cNfK41fK7Wd6l5SqSTNyv" то она успешно декодируется и получится правильный вариант "[2019-04-02 16:00:50"

Но какие бы варианты я не подставлял сюда https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/ не один из них не верен.

Мне необходимо что бы во втором дешефраторе также работала расшифровка, и соответстевнно понять алгоритм.

Comment: А как у вас такой длинный `base64` получился? Кодирую `[2019-04-02 16:00:50` и у меня получился `WzIwMTktMDQtMDIgMTY6MDA6NTA=`

Comment: Этот Base 64 также декодирован из Base 64... тоесть он был кодирован два раза, это уже версия которую дальше без zlib не получится в нормальный вид привести

Comment: Если `WzIwMTktMDQtMDIgMTY6MDA6NTA=` еще раз кодировать base64, то получится `V3pJd01Ua3RNRFF0TURJZ01UWTZNREE2TlRBPQ==`. Напишите, пожалуйста, в самом вопросе как у вас получилась та строка. Кст, я правильно понял, что у вас та строка получилась в следствии сжатия ее через zlib, а после кодирования base64? т.е. псевдокодом `base64(zlib("[2019-04-02 16:00:50"))` так?